# Why does java.util.Map.values() allow you to remove entries from the returned Collection

Tags: java

Why does `java.util.Map.values()` allow you to delete entries from the returned Collection when it makes no sense to remove a key value pair based on the value? The code which does this would have no idea what key the value(and hence a key) being removed is mapped from. Especially when there are duplicate values, calling remove on that Collection would result in an unexpected key being removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it makes no sense to remove a key value pair based on the value

I don't think you're being imaginative enough.  I'll admit there probably isn't *wide* use for it, but there will be valid cases where it would be useful.

As a sample use case, say you had a `Map<Person, TelephoneNumber>` called `contactList`.  Now you want to filter your contact list by those that are local.

To accomplish this, you could make a copy of the map, `localContacts = new HashMap<>(contactList)` and remove all mappings where the `TelephoneNumber` starts with an area code other than your local area code.  This would be a valid time where you want to iterate through the `values` collection and remove some of the values:

```
Map<Person, TelephoneNumber> contactList = getContactList();
Map<Person, TelephoneNumber> localContacts = new HashMap<Person, TelephoneNumber>(contactList);

for ( Iterator<TelephoneNumber> valuesIt = localContacts.values().iterator(); valuesIt.hasNext(); ){
    TelephoneNumber number = valuesIt.next();
    if ( !number.getAreaCode().equals(myAreaCode) ) {
        valuesIt.remove();
    }
}
```

> Especially when there are duplicate values, calling remove on that Collection would result in an unexpected key being removed.

What if you wanted to remove *all* mappings with that value?

Answer (score 6):

It has to have a `remove` method because that's part of `Collection`.  Given that, it has the choice of allowing you to remove values or throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`.  Since there are legitimate reasons that you might want to remove values, why not choose to allow this operation?

- Maybe there's a given value where you want to remove every instance
  of it from the `Map`.
- Maybe you want to trim out every third
  key/value pair for some reason.
- Maybe you have a map from hotel
  room number to occupancy count and you want to remove everything from
  the map where the occupancy count is greater than one in order to
  find a room for someone to stay in.
- ...if you think about it more
  closely, there are plenty more examples like this...

In short: there are plenty of situations where this might be useful and implementing it doesn't harm anyone who doesn't use it, so why not?

Answer (score 0):

The `Collection` returned is a special `Collection`, and its semantics are such that it knows how values in it relate back to the `Map` it came from. The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) indicates what `Collection` operation the returned collection supports.

Comment: The question seems to be about why it's allowed, not how it's done.

Comment: @Kevin - Good point. I seem to have missed that nuance :) I'll leave this answer here anyways, since someone who stumbles onto this question may find it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is quite often a use for removing a value based on a key; other answers show examples.  Given that, if you want to remove a certain value, why would you only want one particular key of it removed?  Even if you did, you'd have to know which key you wanted to remove (or not, as the case may be), and then you should just remove it by key anyway.